# Targetting a ul within with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I target the `<ul>` within `<li class="more-toggle-news">` in `jQuery`:

```
    <ul>
  <li class="more-toggle-news"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-plus"></span><?php the_time('Y'); ?>
    <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I currently have this code:

```
jQuery('li.more-toggle-news').click(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.next('ul').toggle();
    $this.find('span').toggleClass('icon-plus').toggleClass('icon-minus');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery('li.more-toggle-news').click(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.find('ul').toggle();
    $this.find('span').toggleClass('icon-plus').toggleClass('icon-minus');
});
```

first ul:

```
$this.find('ul:eq(0)').toggle();
```

Comment: What if I've got two ul's in li.more-toggle-news and only want to target the first ul?

Comment: @Rob look at my comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('li.more-toggle-news').find('ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.find()` : http://jsfiddle.net/BvbUU/

```
jQuery('li.more-toggle-news').click(function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  $this.find('ul').toggle();
  $this.find('span').toggleClass('icon-plus').toggleClass('icon-minus');
});
```

Also see update with `fadetoggle()` instead of `toggle()' : http://jsfiddle.net/BvbUU/1/

Edit:
 For getting first ul :  http://jsfiddle.net/BvbUU/2/

```
$this.find('ul:first').toggle();
```

or

```
$this.find('ul:eq(0)').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()`

Instead of

```
$this.next('ul').toggle();
```

try

```
$this.find('ul').toggle();
```

`.next()` is used for **siblings** of the element.
But here `ul is a child` . So use `.find()` which will seaxh in its children